# angularjs application is looking like loading(blur)

Tags: angularjs

I have created an angularjs application and am using grunt to run that.When I run the page is displaying but i shows like the page is loading.

This is my app.js code
[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IutwM.png)

This is my UI page looks like and I cant able to click the links

[home.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22IDk.png)

Thanks in advance.......:-)

Comment: can you show your 'managePaymentView.html'?

Comment: And the network tab in your browser as well